# NodeJS splitting buffer by delimter

Tags: json, node.js

I have a basic TCP server in NodeJS which receives JSON strings. These can be multiple strings at a time (delimited by `\n`) or single strings.

The problem arises when i receive multiple ones that are delimited by `\n`.

What I'm trying to do is split the buffer data into an array and then loop over that array to avoid JSON parsing errors.

Here is my current code:

```
var socketServer = net.createServer(function (socket) {

        // Handle incoming messages from agents.
        socket.on('data', function (data) {

                // Split the buffer so we dont get JSON parsing errors
                // Delimiter is \n
                var splitData = splitBuffer(data, "0x5c6e");

                for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {

                    // Error arises here since there are multiple JSONs in the string
                    console.log(JSON.parse(splitData[i]));

                }

        });


});

function splitBuffer(buf, delimiter) {
  var arr = [], p = 0;

  for (var i = 0, l = buf.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (buf[i] !== delimiter) continue;
    if (i === 0) {
      p = 1;
      continue; // skip if it's at the start of buffer
    }
    arr.push(buf.slice(p, i));
    p = i + 1;
  }

  // add final part
  if (p < l) {
    arr.push(buf.slice(p, l));
  }

  return arr;
}
```

For some reason the `splitBuffer()` function is unable to split the buffer according to my delimiter.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: if i understand correctly what you are trying to do, why not turn into a string instead of raw bytes, and use `.split("\n")` method of string i think you will get the result you want.

Comment: This approach might not work because Buffer can be too big(`Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters`). That is why I googled the same question as asker.

Comment: [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) module has [split](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops/wiki/Split) operator that makes it easy to split any iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using ascii representation? It's pretty friendly using javascript's String.charCodeAt(index), which returns a corresponding ascii value. Not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it's something you can try or use in the future.

```
var str = 'thing\n';

var buffer = new Buffer(str.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
    buffer[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if(buffer[i] !== 10) {
        // 10 is \n in ascii
        // do whatever
        console.log(str[i] + ' ' + buffer[i])
    }
  }

// expected output
t 116
h 104
i 105
n 110
g 103
```

Answer (score 0):

String representation might fail on huge buffers with `Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters`. (otherwise it's really better to use `toString().split('\n')`. Also, I wouldn't get here)

```js
function* splitBuffer(buffer, delim){
    let start = 0;
    while(true){
        let nxt = buffer.indexOf(delim, start);
        let chunk;
        if(nxt == -1){
            chunk = buffer.slice(start);
            yield chunk;
            break;
        } else {
            chunk = buffer.slice(start, nxt);
            yield chunk;
        }
        start = nxt+1;
    }
}
```